# Getting data out of mySql database with php in flash builder 4.6

Tags: php, sql, database, apache-flex, flex4.6

In my application I got all the games of Giantbomb. When I click on a game I can see specific information of that game. Now, I created a feature to give your personal score to the game. But now I am trying to print out that score. But It doesn't seem to work

With a http service I try to communicate with my php file and I want to show the 'result' in the function getScoreResult

```
   <s:HTTPService id="getScoreService" url="http://localhost/rma/project/getScore.php" result="getScoreResult(event)" resultFormat="object" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

I also created een arraycollection where I want to put in the data

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="acScore"/>
```

In the function below I declare what i want from the database and put it into the arracollection and I want to fill up the list (or label) with this information.

```
   private function getScoreResult(evt:ResultEvent):void
                {

                        acScore = evt.result.response.data.score;
                        ScoreLabel.dataProvider = acScore;
                        getScoreService.send();
                }   





    <s:Label width="480" text="{data.score}" color="black"/>
        OR

    <s:List id="ScoreLabel">

            </s:List>
```

In my php function I want to get al the information where username = username en the game_url of the specific game is equal to the url of the database. After that I only want to get the specific score.

```
<?php
    $hostname_con = "localhost";
    $username_con = "root";
    $password_con = "";
    $dbname_con = "rma";

    $con = mysql_connect($hostname_con, $username_con, $password_con);
    mysql_select_db($dbname_con);

    session_start();

    $user = $_SESSION["loggedIn"];
    $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["url"]);
    $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["score"]);

    $select = "SELECT * FROM gamesscore WHERE user_name = '" . $user . "' AND game_url = '" . $url . "';";
    $result = $db->conn->query($select);

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    echo "<response>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<data>";
        echo "<score>" . $row["game_score"] . "</score>";
        echo "</data>";
    }
    echo "</response>";

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Should getScoreService.send(); not be called in the initializer, or on a button event? It will then come back and call getScoreResult(); ? You will have an endless loop running here...

Comment: Declare the resultformat as xml, not as an object

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this, but it is a very different structure to yours:

```
<s:HTTPServicer resultFormat="xml" id="xService" url="blabla.net.au/Api/xxx/" result="onResult(event)"  />
```

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <response>
>     <data>
>         <score>10</score>
>     </data>    
> </response>
> ```

Mine was:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
<companyID>xxxxxxx-1267-440F-B3A3-9DF7F3295274</companyID>
<url>http://localhost:6988/</url>
<logourl></logourl>
<QuietStartTime>22</QuietStartTime>
<QuietEndTime>5</QuietEndTime>
<headername>Colonel Light Hotel</headername>
<headercolor>#008CC7</headercolor>
<bodycolor>#008CC7</bodycolor>
<fontcolor>#ffffff</fontcolor>
<textboxcolor>#008CC7</textboxcolor>
</settings>
```

At some point I was able to reference it as

```
companyID:String = event.result.settings.companyID;



[Bindable]
public var dataArr2:ArrayCollection;

dataArr2 = new ArrayCollection();   
var result:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
result.ignoreWhite = true;
result.parseXML(e.target.data); 
parseCompanyData(result.firstChild);
```

And the function that added the data to the data array...

```
private function parseCompanyData(node:XMLNode):void {          

    //Get single row
    var rows:Array = node.childNodes;
    var Record:Array = new Array(22);
    var i:Number = 0;

    for (var j:int=0; j<22; j++){
        if(rows[j].childNodes.length > 0){
            Record[j] = rows[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
        }
        else {
            Record[j] = rows[j].nodeValue;                          
        }                       
    }   
    dataArr2.addItem({ Score: Record[0]});
}
```

Not sure if this will be of any use to you.

You can also look at doing a REST service in your PHP, and bind to that using the wizards...

Hope something helps

You can also have parameters for your service like:

```
<mx:HTTPService result="handleXML(event);" fault="handleFault(event);" id="xmlRPC2" resultFormat="e4x"
        url="{serviceurl}default.aspx">
        <!--http://www.visualrecruit.net/default.aspx">-->
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <MailServer>{PopServer.text}</MailServer>
            <MailPort>{PopPort.text}</MailPort>
            <Usr>{Usr.text}</Usr>
            <Pass>{Pass.text}</Pass>
            <SSL>{SSL.value}</SSL>
            <archive>{MsgID.text}</archive>
            <folder>INBOX.archive</folder>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>
```

In this function I had to go quite a few levels down, but could bind to my dataArr anywhere.

```
private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void 
{   

    dataArr = new ArrayCollection();

    myXML = new XML(event.result);

    var result:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    result.ignoreWhite = true;
    result.parseXML(event.result.toString());   

    myGroup.removeAllElements();

    var counter:int = 0;
    var node1:XMLNode = result.firstChild;
    var rows:Array = node1.childNodes;
    for each(var row:XMLNode in rows) { 
        var kids:Array = row.childNodes;
        var itemArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        //Get the root item
        var Record:Array = new Array(11);

        for (var j:int=0; j<11; j++){
            if(kids[j].childNodes.length > 0){
                Record[j] = kids[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
            else {
                Record[j] = kids[j].nodeValue;                          
            }                       
        }       
        dataArr.addItem({ Coordinates1: Record[0],Coordinates2: Record[1],DeviceID: Record[2],DeviceName: Record[3],LightColor: Record[4],LocationID: Record[5],RecordId: Record[6],Status: Record[7],Type: Record[8],XOffset: Record[9],YOffset: Record[10]}); 

        var rex:RegExp = /[\s\r\n]+/gim;

        var myButton:Label = new Label(); 
        myButton.text = ""; 
        myButton.top = counter;
        myButton.height = 100;
        myButton.width = 100;
        myButton.setStyle("backgroundColor", Record[7].replace(rex,''));
        myGroup.addElement(myButton);                   

        counter += 100;
    }
}
```

With a group object...

```
<s:Group id="myGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
```

Comment: Updated the last line, to reflect your a bit more. Can you paste the actual xml output?

Comment: There is no output.. It shows nothing? The list is empty

Comment: I meant the xml output in the browser from the php page. Yoo have to have some output to start with...

Comment: My service is declared as: <s:HTTPService id="xService" url="http://blabla.net.au/Api/xxx/" result="onResult(event)" resultFormat="xml" />